# Error preparing MediaPlayer

Tags: android, path, uri, android-mediaplayer, android-external-storage

My application consists of uploading a single media file from the users SDcard and uploading it to a listview. That part it self, works perfectly. Each uri is saved under an SQlite database which saves the files in the listview as well.

However, Now I am trying to obtain its path and URI on itemClick so I am able to Start playing any audio file I want.

The issue is that the URI is getting an error when I start to prepare it. I'm not sure if I formatted everything correctly, as I receive this error:

```
08-18 13:11:12.790 24401-25067/com.example.daniel.queue E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
```

I understand this error could mean a few things, but please, let me know if I am formatting my URI or path correctly.  I have my permissions so that is not the issue. I assume it may be a formatting issue but I am yet to find a solution.

```
private void ItemClick() {

    user_music_reccomadatons.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String pos = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Uri uriFile = Uri.fromFile(new File(pos));  //creates a Uri from a file
            String pathFile =   uriFile.getEncodedPath();  //gets coded path
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageState() + pathFile;
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uriFile);
                Log.d("DATA SOURCE"," GOT DATA SOURCE " + path);

            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d("ERROR", "ERROR ON SETDATASOURCE");
            }
            try {
                mp.prepare();
                Log.d("Success!","");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("error", " ERROR PREPARING");

            }


            Log.d("data", "URI: "+ uriFile + " PATH "+ pathFile);
            Log.d("ENVI PATH", " path: "+ path);





              }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your setDataSource is not returning any error?

Comment: Not that Ive seen in the logcat.. the main error line seems to be what I posted

Comment: How am I able to find the path for any uri file that I click on the list view thats on my sdcard?

Comment: I feel like that could be a possible solution but Im not sure how to implement it...

Comment: Just hardcode the one file path for testing